# How to create a layout responsive in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive

I am new to Flutter and I am having some problems when it comes to making a responsive web app.
The layout I'm trying to make is similar to the one shown below,

[the image is a prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlskz.png)

but when I resize the screens, everything gets distorted.
I have tried using the responsive widgets but there is no case.

PD: Sorry for my bad english !

```
class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final childrenHorizontal = [
      Expanded(flex: 2150, child: RectanguloIzquierdaHorizontal()),
      Expanded(flex: 1850, child: RectanguloDerechaHorizontal()),
    ];

    final childrenVertical = [
      Expanded(child: RectanguloIzquierdaVertical()),
      Expanded(child: RectanguloDerechaVertical())
    ];

    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: null,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.menu_rounded,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 35,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30)),
        ],
        // leading: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white,),#
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Title',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        elevation: 1,
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constrains) {
          return (constrains.maxWidth < 600)
              ? Column(
                  children: childrenVertical,
                )
              : SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Row(
                    children: childrenHorizontal,
                  ),
                );
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color.cyan,
      bottomNavigationBar: ScreenFooter(screenSize: _screenSize),
    );
  }
}

class RectanguloIzquierdaHorizontal extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RectanguloIzquierdaHorizontalState createState() =>
      _RectanguloIzquierdaHorizontalState();
}

class _RectanguloIzquierdaHorizontalState
    extends State<RectanguloIzquierdaHorizontal> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final padding = _screenSize.width * .1;
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: padding),
      child: Container(
        width: _screenSize.width * 1.2,
        height: 800,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _screenSize.height * .125)),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: _screenSize.width * .03,
                  right: _screenSize.width * .04),
              child: AutoSizeText(
                "TEXT TEXT TEXT"                ,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,                  
                    color: Colors.white),
                maxFontSize: 16,
                minFontSize: 12,
                maxLines: 6,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: _screenSize.width * .02,
                  right: _screenSize.width * .13),
              child: AutoSizeText(
                "TEXT TEX TEX",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 100,                   
                  ),
                maxFontSize: 100,
                minFontSize: 30,
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 45, right: 50),
              height: _screenSize.height * .50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.purple,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                    spreadRadius: 2.0,
                    offset: Offset(2.0, 10),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                      spreadRadius: 2.0,
                      offset: Offset(2.0, 10),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, left: 7, right: 7),
                height: _screenSize.width * .50,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black26,
                        blurRadius: 10.0,
                        spreadRadius: 2.0,
                        offset: Offset(2.0, 10),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, left: 7, right: 7),
                  height: _screenSize.height * .50,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RectanguloDerechaHorizontal extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RectanguloDerechaHorizontalState createState() =>
      _RectanguloDerechaHorizontalState();
}

class _RectanguloDerechaHorizontalState
    extends State<RectanguloDerechaHorizontal> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final padding = _screenSize.width * .1;
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: padding),
      child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 800,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: Column(children: [
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _screenSize.height * .06)),
            Expanded(
              flex: 100,
              child: Container(
                //color: Colors.red,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _screenSize.height * .2)),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: _screenSize.height * .01,
                            left: _screenSize.width * .03),
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage(
                              'image'),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _screenSize.height * .05)),
            Expanded(
              flex: 50,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: _screenSize.width * .050),
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  'TEXT',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 80,                   
                    
                      height: 0.85),
                  maxFontSize: 80,
                  minFontSize: 30,
                  maxLines: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 50,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: _screenSize.width * 0.010),
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  'TEXT',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 80,                     
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 0.85),
                  maxFontSize: 80,
                  minFontSize: 30,
                  maxLines: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 50,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: _screenSize.width * 0.165),
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  'TEXT',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 80, 
                      height: 0.85),
                  maxFontSize: 80,
                  minFontSize: 30,
                  maxLines: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 300,
              child: Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 265, left: _screenSize.width * .040),
                      child: Text(
                        'TEXT',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 60,                          
                         
                            height: 0.85),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                child: Image(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                  'image'),
                              height: 288,
                              width: 288,
                            )),
                            Container(
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => SelectAge()),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  'BUTTON',
                                  style: TextStyle(                                        
                                     
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                    
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please have a look for adaptive layout https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive

Answer (score 0):

i using a small widget to fix that issue

```
class CustomLayoutSize extends StatelessWidget {
  final int size;
  final Widget larger;
  final Widget lessOrEqual;
  const CustomLayoutSize(
      {Key? key,
      required this.size,
      required this.larger,
      required this.lessOrEqual})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constrains) {
        return (constrains.maxWidth < size) ? larger : lessOrEqual;
      },
    );
  }
}
```